# $this->request->data only taking the user's ID when trying to edit CAKEPHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm new to using CakePHP and at the moment I'm try to allow the user to edit it's own personal details.

But although the function seems to work (it tells me the user has been updated) It doesn't actually update the user's details.

I used the debugger on $this->request->data and all it seems to show is the user id of the user that's logged in.

Here is my function

```
public function useredit() {
        $this->User->id = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        $this->request->data = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
        if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
            //debug($this->request->data);
            //exit;
            if ($this->User->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The user has been saved', true));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The User could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        } else {
            $this->request->data = $this->User->read(null);
            isset($this->request->data['User']['password']);
        }
    }
```

Here is my view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'useredit'));
echo $this->Form->input('id', array('type' => 'hidden'));
echo $this->Form->input('username', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.username')));
//echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->input('name', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.name')));
echo $this->Form->input('surname', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.surname')));
echo $this->Form->input('address1', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.address1')));
echo $this->Form->input('address2', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.address2')));
echo $this->Form->input('town', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.town')));
echo $this->Form->input('postCode', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.postCode')));
echo $this->Form->input('dob', array ('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.dob')
                                        , 'label' => 'Date of Birth'
                                        , 'dateFormat' => 'DMY'
                                        , 'empty' => array('DATE','MONTH','YEAR')
                                        , 'minYear' => date('Y') - 110
                                        , 'maxYear' => date('Y') - 0));
echo $this->Form->input('emailAddress', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.emailAddress')));
echo $this->Form->input('phoneNumber', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.phoneNumber')));
echo $this->Form->input('mobileNumber', array('value' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.mobileNumber')));
echo $this->Form->end('Submit');
?>
```

Any help in working out why this wont save any other data other than the id would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: no need in specifying `'action' => 'useredit'` - it posts to itself by default!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->request->data = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');
```

is wrong.
Also do not set any defaults in your form view. Rely on the data passed down from the controller.

you probably mean

```
$this->request->data = $this->Session->read('Auth');
```

But even then you are reading "old data" from the session.
Use find(first) and provide the `'Auth.User.id'` only to query the right record.
Pass this record then down to the view as `$this->request->data`.
On save, make sure the id is present and it will update correctly.

See http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/10/05/common-cakephp-problems-and-solutions/ on how to do it properly. Note that for 2.x its $this->request->data instead of $this->data.
Also use `if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {}` for 2.x
But the basic idea should become clear.

Comment: This has fixed the array $this->request->data, but my edit user changes are not being completed

Comment: Thanks Mark, after that i realized that i should call the `$this->request->data['User']['id'] = $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id');` after the `if ($this->request->is('post')) {`

Comment: Jep :) And don't forget the security component and/or whitelisting to prevent tempering as outlined in the link.